# JQuery make html insert look nicer

Tags: jquery

I insert a web form after initialising a successful connection with socket.io server. It looks like this:

```
    $('#login').append('<div class="title">typical title</div>');
    $('#login').append('<div class="subtitle">enter wittiness here</div>');
    $('#login').append('<form><hr>');
    $('#login form').append('<div style="text-align:center;"> Username: <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." id="username" name="username"></div>');
    $('#login form').append('<div style="text-align:center;"> Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password" name="password"></div>');
    $('#login form').append('<hr width="80%" /><input type="submit" class="login" value="Log in!" /><input type="button" class="register" value="Registration" />');
```

In my opinion that doesn't look as nice, is there a way I can either load this html snippet or make this code look nicer, it's on client-side too so everyone can look up this ugliness...

Comment: you could use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You could just use HTML and include where you need it.

Comment: @CayceK hmm, interesting idea.. I might or might not end up with ajax.

Comment: Put it in your html. Hidden by default and just show it when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set it to display:none or can hide it with hide() method and then show it after append()

For example first make a node and hide it (**hide()** is adding display:none) so same

```
node=$('<div style="text-align:center;"></div>').hide();
```

then append the node and use any effect from show,fadeIn,slidedown will show it

**Show()**

```
$('#login form').append(node).show("slow");
```

**fadeIn()** will look even more nicer

```
$('#login form').append(node).fadeIn("slow");
```

You can look sliding effect as well

**slideDown()**

```
$('#login form').append(node).slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: I don't know how I feel about it since in case of connection error... I will think of that, thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#login').append('<div class="title">typical title</div><div class="subtitle">enter wittiness here</div><form><hr>');
$('#login form').append('<div style="text-align:center;"> Username: <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." id="username" name="username"></div><div style="text-align:center;"> Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password" name="password"></div><hr width="80%" /><input type="submit" class="login" value="Log in!" /><input type="button" class="register" value="Registration" />');
```